# c++ overwrite already opened file

Tags: c++, io

I am opening a file with `ifstream` to check if it exists. Then I close it and open it with `ofstream` to write to it, and I think setting `ios::trunc` flag allows me to overwrite it.

However I'd like the ability to keep the file open if it exists, but I used an `ifstream` to open it so does that mean I can't write to the file till I close and re-open using `fstream` or `ofstream`? I didn't use `fstream` to begin with because that wouldn't tell me if the file was already there or not.

Comment: Consider using a function to check for file existence, instead of going all the way to actually open the file.

Comment: @K-ballo Opening the file actually is the only halfway reliable way of doing this. And even that can fail of course, the file system being asynchronous and all.

Comment: It seems trying to make an `ifstream` was the standard C++ way to find existence of file. Just check `ifstream::good()`. Konrad beat me to it.

Comment: Okay, how about taking it in a different direction. Is there a way to do this (i.e. determine if a file exists, then overwrite it (or not, depending on its contents), without requiring open-close-open-close) using `FILE*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open a read-write `fstream` on the file.  You can test if the file previously existed (and was non-empty) by seeking to the end and seeing if you're at a non-zero offset.  If so, the file existed, and you can do whatever with it.  If not, the file didn't exist or was empty.  Assuming you don't need to distinguish between those two cases, you can then proceed as if it did not exist.

For example:

```
// Error checking omitted for expository purposes
std::fstream f("file.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
f.seekg(0, std::ios::end)
bool didFileExist = (f.tellg() > 0);
f.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

// Now use the file in read-write mode.  If didFileExist is true, then the
// file previously existed (and has not yet been modified)
```

Comment: Good insight here. This wouldn't let me find out if the file existed as a 0-byte file, but that single case hardly matters at all. For all intents and purposes, an empty file is about as meaningful as a file that doesn't even exist. I think I will do it this way.

Comment: Incidentally, is this not possible with `fopen`? According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/ using `w+` will erase the file upon opening. I'd be using `r+` instead? And when that fails I can just use `w`, knowing it's a new file.

Comment: @Steven: The equivalent with `fopen` would be to use the `r+` mode.

Answer (score 1):

The setting `ios::trunc` erases previous contents of the file.
Try opening the file without this setting; with only the 'write' setting.

Comment: Could you clarify? Is there a way to modify the flags after the file's been already opened (via the ctor)?

Comment: I don't think this allows him to check if a file exists.

Comment: @Thomas: please elaborate, this doesn't answer the question

Comment: The `ios::trunc` will discard any information in the file before writing.  Removing this will solve the OP's problem of overwriting existing content without erasing the content; as `ios::trunc` erases existing content.

Comment: As far as testing for existence of a file, the only *standard* method is to open the file for reading and checking the return value.  There may be better platform specific methods, but this is the only standard method.

Comment: @Thomas I think I get what you mean. No, I wanted to avoid the behavior of "overwriting without erasing", i.e. original file contents "abcdef" and writing in "123" yields "123def". I wanted to make sure that when I did overwrite that I would be making a completely new file.

Answer (score 0):

this is touching very serios problem - race conditions - what if somebody manages to do something with this file between closing and reopening? unfortunately iostream does not provide any means of resolving that issue - you can use cstdio FILE. If you want to turncate file if exists or create new one if not use fopen(name, "w"). If you want to turncate file if it exists or fail otherwise, then it seems standard library has nothing to offer, and you should go to other libraries or platform specific functions like OpenFile in windows.h

Comment: Yes you bring up a good point. Right now my code opens the file to check if it existed in the ctor of my `Reader` class and it has a member function `writeData(void *data)` which fills it with image data. Any process can screw with that file between those operations which is partly why I wanted a single open rather than open-close-reopen.